# Bash - kill ALL parallel processes if one fails

Tags: bash

I have 2 processes that I run via:

```
init_thing & start_thing
```

`init_thing` polls the logs of `start_thing` for a particular line that it considers to show that `start_thing` has successfully begun, then executes a few commands against it (e.g. adding users).

The `init_thing` function could fail with a non-zero exit code if it considers `start_thing` to have timed out.
The `start_thing` function could fail, but if successful it runs forever.

What I want to do is kill `start_thing` if `init_thing` fails.

I've seen use of GNU `parallel` in a lot of answers, but it seems to rely on both processes completing (i.e. exiting with a zero exit-code), which in my case doesn't apply.

Is there a way to do this with bash? Perhaps using `parallel` in a way that I haven't seen/understood?

Comment: `start_thing & pid=$!; if ! init_thing; then kill "$pid"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

trap ERR may be useful, where pid variable contains the pid of process to kill

```
trap 'kill $pid' ERR
```

after reflexion it is clearer to write explicitly

```
init_thing || {
    echo "something goes wrong, killing $pid"
    kill "$pid"
}
```